# Symfony2 Class UserInterface does not exist

Tags: symfony, user-interface

I'm making a customer case management system with Symfony 2.1 and I've stumbled on this weird problem I'm unable to resolve. For some reason when I do the showAction with `CustomerCaseController`, I get the following error:

> "Class HSW\AshaBundle\Entity\UserInterface does not exist"
>   500 Internal Server Error

I have no idea which part of the application is requiring that interface. **If I create an empty `UserInterface.php` class, the problem goes away** and everything works. Why does the `showAction` require `UserInterface`?

I have narrowed the problem to somehow relate to this piece of code in the showController:

```
$customercase = $this->getDoctrine() ->getRepository('HSWAshaBundle:CustomerCase') ->find($id);
```

I have the following entities:

- `User` (for login and submitting cases)
- `Customer` (for Customers)
- `CustomerCase` (for cases).

The `CustomerCase` has a ManyToOne relation with `Customer` and `User` entities in the following way:

**// src/HSW/AshaBundle/Entity/CustomerCase.php**
    namespace HSW\AshaBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * CustomerCase
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="hsw_customerCase")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class CustomerCase
{

/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="customerCases") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $customer;

/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="createdCustomerCases") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $creator;

/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="holdingCustomerCases") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="holder_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $holder;
.....etc....
```

**// src/HSW/AshaBundle/Entity/CustomerCase.php**
    namespace HSW\AshaBundle\Entity;

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * HSW\AshaBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="hsw_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="HSW\AshaBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
.....etc....
```

**Could the relationship with the User entity affect this somehow?** That's the only visible difference I see between `CustomerCase.php` and `Customer.php` (where `showAction` works without `UserInterface`).

Can someone help me to debug this behaviour?. It seems really useless to have an empty `UserInterface` class only because Symfony requires is (for an unknown reason).

Comment: Can you edit your post and show your namespace declarations and use statements in CustomerCase and User entities?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I just added the beginning parts for both Entities. I'm using AdvancedUserInterface for login (to allow login with email). Could this somehow be the reason for these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't import [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html)'s namespace into your user class (I'm guessing it's a User class since you didn't mention it):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface
{
}
```

Read on [PHP namespaces in the official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: Hi Jakub and thank you very much! This actually seemed to fix the situation. I was a bit sceptic first, because my User class didn't implement UserInterface directly (it used AdvancedUserInterface). I'm still a bit confused about what triggered this specific problem? I was fully able to make a createAction for CustomerCase an login/logout without importing UserInterface namespace.